# how can I append this product to wishes relation?

Tags: javascript, pocketbase

```
  const currentUser = usePbAuth().user;

  async function addToWishlist() {
    try {
      const updatedUser = await pb.collection('users').update(currentUser.id, {
        "wishes": productId,
      });
  }
```

How can I add the current relation while maintaining the existing data when only the relation to be added is inserted and the existing wishes relation is deleted?

I want to append the current product to "wishes".

Answer (score 0):

You can [append the product](https://pocketbase.io/docs/working-with-relations#append-to-multiple-relation) like this:

```js
const updatedUser = await pb.collection('users').update(currentUser.id, {
   "wishes+": productId,
})
```

The `+` after `wishes` tells pocketbase to append that product to the user's wishes.

##### Append multiple products

Pocketbase also allows you to append multiple products to a user's wishes:

```js
const updatedUser = await pb.collection('users').update(currentUser.id, {
   "wishes+": [...products],
})
```